# What does "matched by" mean here?

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the following paragraph from [this article](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/comment/2013/08/obama-surveillance-and-the-legacy-of-the-march-on-washington.html):

> We’ve compressed the grand scale of the March on Washington—which took place on August 28, 1963, fifty years ago this coming Wednesday—into succinct quotes, a vine of grainy footage of Martin Luther King, Jr., at the crowded dais, and a dream metaphor whose ubiquity is **matched only by its** anodyne appeal.

I don't understand "matched only by" as used in this sentence.
It means to be on the same level... but it doesn't make sense here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

‘To be matched by’ does indeed, as you say, mean [to be on the same level as](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/match) (see *verb*, def. 2).

In the phrase *X is matched **only** by Y*, the meaning is that *the only thing is equal to X is Y*. In other words, to paraphrase your example:

> The only thing that is equal to the *ubiquity* of this dream metaphor is the *anodyne appeal* of the dream metaphor

Whether it is true that the metaphor used by Martin Luther King, Jr., in his famous “I have a dream” speech is ‘anodyne’ (deliberately inoffensive and placid) is of course a matter of opinion; but the writer of the article clearly seems to think so, because he is specifically saying that even though the metaphor is as well-known and ubiquitous (found everywhere) as it is, it is just as inoffensively placid as it is well-known. In other words, he thinks it is extremely inoffensive and placid.